# Referencia nula al hacer POST con Volley

Tags: java, android, json

Codigo de error:
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference**

Codigo:

```
public void agregar_Paciente(View v){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("Holalalala");
                        //Log.d("Response", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        // error

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                System.out.println("========================================================================================");
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("nombre", nombre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("apellido_paterno", ap_P.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("apellido_materno", ap_M.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("num_telefono", tel.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("edad", edad.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("sexo", sexo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("direccion", dir.getText().toString());

                return parametros;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(request);
        queue.add(request);


    }
```

A la hora de consumir la Api salta un error de que estoy pasando una referencia nula en el queue no se porque pasa estoy ya llevo un rato tratando de solucionarlo y no pude alguien sabra que esta pasando?

Comment: ¿Dónde creas a `queue`? Es `queue` lo que te dice que es nulo.

Comment: Lo creo como atributo de la clase  así RequestQueue queue;

Comment: Pero tienes que inicializarla de algún modo, por ejemplo, poniendo esto al inicio del método: `queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Oh ya eso me faltaba gracias amigo enserió te lo agradezco de todo corazón